# Custom success messages in Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, modelstate

I would like to return different success messages when a record is successfully updated in my Kendo grid (inline editing).  What I would like to do is something like this (returning a pop-up similar to ModelState.AddModelError, only as a success message).  I know ModelState doesn't have an equivalent for "Success" so I'm wondering how this might be achieved.

```
if (MyBool == true)
{
  //custom message one
}
else
{
  //custom message two
}

return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [requestEnd](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DataSourceEventBuilder#methods-RequestEnd(System.String)) event of the DataSource to check if the current operation is "create" or "update" and there is no errors to alert the user.

Sample MVC Wrapper

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Title("Product Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Title("Unit Price");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Title("Units In Stock");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        // below is the RequestEnd event handler 
        .Events(events => events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))        
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
     )
)
```

and here is the event handler

```
function onRequestEnd(e) {        
    if (e.type == "update" && !e.response.Errors) {
       // Update record is successfull, show your desired message
    }

    if (e.type == "create" && !e.response.Errors) {
       // Create record is successfull, show your desired message
    }
}
```